# partial sum of absolute value of cosine

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to show what the value of
$\sum_1^{N}|\cos(\frac{\pi(n-1)}{N})|$ and $\sum_1^{N}|\cos(\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2N})|$ are.  A plug into Wolfram yields that the former is $\csc{\frac{\pi}{2N}}\sin{\frac{2\pi \left \lfloor{\frac{N}{2}+\pi}\right \rfloor }{2N}}$ and the latter is $\csc{\frac{\pi}{2N}}\sin{\frac{\pi \left \lfloor{\frac{N+1}{2}}\right \rfloor }{N}}$ (it is the floor function in brackets).  But I am not sure how to get this at all.  I know that one can apply Euler's formula to show the partial sums of sines and cosines, but the absolute values are really throwing me off here.  Would appreciate any help I can get.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you swap the $n$ and $pi$ in the sums?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! Thanks, it's fixed now.

Comment: Hint: Try to look at the sign of $\cos\frac{\pi(n-1)}N$